# How to pass argument from onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, function, onclick

I have created a table and populated it using jQuery. Now I would like to add a text such as when we click on it a function executes. I have used `onclick` and it worked fine, but I also need to send a few arguments to my function, how can I send arguments to the targeted function from `onclick`:

```js
var dataHtml = '';
$.each(data, function (index, user) {
    dataHtml+="<code onclick=show_popup(1,user['donner'][0])> Donner details</code>";
});
$("#t-data").html(dataHtml);

function show_popup(show=0, donner){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var showModel=show;
    if(showModel==`1`){
        $(`#modal-default-admin`).modal(`show`);
    }
});
```

But it shows a "user is not defined" error. User is defined and I also can access it.

Comment: `var showModel=show;` is redundant.

Comment: Also, *model* != *modal*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user` is in fact not defined. The problem you are facing is that you are using HTML as a string, so you are providing `onclick=show_popup(1,user['donner'][0])` as string. When jQuery "makes HTML" out of this string and you click on it, it calls `show_popup` with `1` and `user['donner'][0]` and the `user` here is undefined. It was only available inside the `$.each` loop, not outside of it.

The simplest fix is to pass the value directly and not trying to do it as a pointer.

```
onclick=show_popup(1,\""+ user['donner'][0] +"\")>
```

Like this, it will use the *value* of `user['donner'][0]` when creating the HTML.

Bonus point: You should wrap the onclick attribute with quotes:

```
dataHtml += "<code onclick='show_popup(1,\""+ user['donner'][0] +"\")'> Donner details</code>";
```

Just to make sure that for example a space in the value of `user['donner'][0]` doesn't break it again.

Comment: after doing this it display an error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. If i dont pass user['donner'] then it shows popup

Comment: I updated the snippet, I had more missing quotes

Comment: dataHtml+="<code onclick=show_popup(1,'{{user['donner'][0]}}')> Donner details</code>"

Comment: @JakubKotrs It worked.!! But There's a problem that it actually prints the object as a string. I change that object to an indexed array using this :
`var result = Object.keys(user['donner'][0]).map((key) => [key, user['donner'][0][key]]);`
but it convert this in string in KEY,VALUE,KEY,VALUE,KEY.... format. How can I pass it such that It remains an array

Comment: @JakubKotrs I created a JS variable , a string HTML table with all donner infor and then just pass it to show donner and use it. It worked fine. Thank you

Comment: It's probably now the time to tell you that using string to create HTML elements like this is not a good thing in the long run. You should consider more programatic approach. In jQuery, you can do `$('<code />').on('click', () => show_popup(1, user.doner[0]))` just fine. This creates a new code element and attaches an event listener. Next, you can add the text content using `.text('content')` and so on.